# Linker error during calling instantiated function

Tags: c++, templates

The following code produces the linker error:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    void foo(int);
    template<class V> void foo(V v){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

A<int> a;
int main(){ a.foo(3); } //Here is the error.
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d25ba301cd563bf8)**

But the following code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template<class V> void foo(V v){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

A<int> a;
int main(){ a.foo(3); } //OK, call to foo<int>
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31479c8ea1034ce6)**

Why didn't the first example cause implicit instatiation of the member, but the second did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other things being equal, non-template functions are preferred over function templates in overload resolution. In your first example, in `A<int>.foo(3);`, the candidates are the non-template `void foo(int)` and the template `template<class V> void foo(V)` with `V = int`. After substitution, the signatures are identical, and so the tiebreaker in [over.match.best]/p1.6 applies:

> a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another
>   viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a
>   worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> - [several inapplicable bullets omitted]
> - `F1` is not a function template specialization and `F2` is a function template specialization
> - [inapplicable bullet omitted]

Hence, `A<int>.foo(3);` unambiguously resolves to the non-template `foo()`, for which you didn't provide a definition, thus the linker error.

Comment: But why don't we get a redefinition error in [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c621db14dea8a9c) example? We provided definitions both for function and function template. The implicit instantiation of `A<int>`  causes the implicit instatiation of `A<int>::foo` thus in fact we have two defined member function with the name `foo`. There must be an error about redifinition, I think....

Comment: I'm sorry, i was wrong about _The implicit instantiation of `A<int>` causes the implicit instatiation of `A<int>::foo`_. It actually was caused by usage the function template in the class member access expression. But it's still not clear about _redifinition error_. I think It should have been printed.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Why will there be a redefinition error? The function and the function template are separate entities; they overload.

Comment: But implicit instatiation of the function template is a function, not a function template. That why I think the redefinition error. So, it violates _3.2/4 [basic.def.odr]_

Comment: @DmitryFucintv No. `foo<int>` and `foo` are distinct entities.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think that in the first case, compiler does not know which foo function you want. foo(3) can match to both `void foo(int);` and `template<class V> void foo(V v)`. To correct this, in main just explicitly tell that you want the template version:

```
 a.foo<int>(3); // or just  a.foo<>(3);
```

In the second case, you have only one foo function. So there is no problem.

Comment: It does know which one you want, or it won't be a linker error.

Comment: @T.C. Than what is the reason? Maybe my wording is incorrect or  the whole answer is incorrect?